# No entiendo el comportamiento de las variables

Tags: c++

He resuelto un ejercicio para mi carrera de estudiante.

```
main ()

int cantAlumnos = 0;
int A,B,C,D,R=0;
int nota;

while (cantAlumnos < 12)
{
    cout << "Ingrese Nota: ";
    cin >> nota;
    if ((90 <= nota)&&(nota <= 100))
    {
        A++;
        cantAlumnos++;
    }
    else if ((80 <= nota)&&(nota< 90))
    {
        B++;
        cantAlumnos++;
    }
    else if ((70 <= nota)&&(nota< 80))
    {
        C++;
        cantAlumnos++;
    }
    else if ((60 <= nota)&&(nota< 70))
    {
        D++;
        cantAlumnos++;
    }
    else if ((0 <= nota)&&(nota< 60))
    {
        R++;
        cantAlumnos++;
    }
    else if ((0 > nota) || (nota > 100)) 
    {
        cout << "Nota invalida" << endl;
    }
}
cout << "Puntajes A: " << A << endl;
cout << "Puntajes B: " << B << endl;
cout << "Puntajes C: " << C << endl;
cout << "Puntajes D: " << D << endl;
cout << "Puntajes R: " << R << endl;
```

Si las variables han sido inicializadas en `0`, ¿Por qué si no se modifica su valor luego de la ejecución del `while`, imprimen en pantalla valores aleatorios?

Nota: Ejemplo, ingreso 12 veces 99 y devuelve:

```
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Ingrese Nota: 99
Puntajes A: 12
Puntajes B: 4196854
Puntajes C: -708719728
Puntajes D: 0
Puntajes R: 0
```

Comment: Si es menor a 90, también es menor a 100.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos que entras y los datos que recibes como salida?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus int a,b,etc=3 no le da valor solo a etc? el resto tiene cualquier valor?

Answer (score 4):

> Nota: ejemplo ingreso 12 veces 99 y devuelve: Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Ingrese Nota: 99 Puntajes A: 12 Puntajes B: 4196854 Puntajes C: -708719728 Puntajes D: 0 Puntajes R: 0

Estos valores raros se producen porque **no has inicializado** las variables:

```
//          ~ <- variable incializada
int A,B,C,D,R=0;
//  ~ ~ ~ ~   <- variables sin inicializar
```

La solución es tan simple como inicializar las variables:

```
int A=0, B=0, C=0, D=0, R=0;
```

Comment: @aloMalbarez cierto. Mil disculpas... contesté rápido y metí la pata con eso

Comment: Gracias por contestar: Creí haber leído que se podían inicializar multiples variables con el mismo valor separados por una copa; pero al parecer no es así.